# How to stream data from one ubuntu terminal to another terminal

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to stream a data (random) from my virtual instance on AWS EC2 ubuntu machine. I have a python script that generates some random data on the terminal. I want  to get this stream of data on my local machine (again ubuntu) on the terminal. I am connected to AWS instance using ssh (Remmina) so if this is possible using ssh that would be a great help. else any new method is welcome ( I was hoping TCP server-client method)

Comment: Unclear: as soon as you are connected through ssh on your local machine to the virtual machine running the script, you see that data on your terminal on the local machine, i.e., it is streamed already to your machine. Specify more clearly what you precisely want to achieve.

Comment: tmux or screen will allow you to have multiple terminals connected to the same pseudo tty on a remote box..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the tmux package is installed on your remote EC2 box

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

Then when you run your python script run 'tmux new-session' and when that give you a new shell prompt run your python script.

Your script will then run under tmux..  And you can detach from tmux without effecting your program by doing a cntl-b + d.    You'll go back to your origin shell.

When you want to monitor or check it run `tmux attach` you can do this multiple times from different logins.  If you want to run multiple scripts you can run multiple tmux instances and name them if required.

When you exit the shell to run your script in the tmux session will end. or you can do cntl-x and that will terminate the session.

More information on using tmux and some of its basic features here:-
https://www.howtogeek.com/671422/how-to-use-tmux-on-linux-and-why-its-better-than-screen/